# How do I remove the automatic updates from Dota2 Workshop?

Tags: steam, dota-2

I've already unchecked the DLC stuff on Dota2 page and disabled download DLC on Steam options in Dota2. I don't have any arcade games installed on it. Why does it keep downloading?

Comment: The vanilla game itself Dota 2 has many updates, often weekly, that need to be downloaded before play. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a regular update?

Answer (score 1):

You've subscribed to workshop items, and the game is keeping them up-to-date as a result.

Custom games including overthrow and 10vs10 are also updated as workshop items.

You can view 'subscribed' workshop items by going to [This Page](http://steamcommunity.com/my/myworkshopfiles?&browsefilter=mysubscriptions)

Or by going via your profile by choosing 'Workshop Items'

[image]

and clicking the 'Subscribed Items' button in the lower right.

[image]

you will then be able to Unsubscribe from anything you don't want to play.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*use this at your own risk
RENAME or move THE DOTA 2 FOLDER
Then uninstall Dota 2. When you want it again rename/move the folder back. You will still have to validate all files but at least you will not have to download everything again.
(also works for all games if you rename or move the steamapps folder)(you can then move the games you want updated to the steamapps/common folder)